# Laravel, do..while loop loops infinitely?

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I have a loop function to work until there are no matches in my database so that I could get a unique string. However, for some reason, my loop is infinite. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
do {
   $testvar = Str::random(5);
   $data = User::where('password_url', 'LIKE', '%'.$testvar.'%')->get();
}
   while (!empty($data));
```

The thing is that I do not get any error messages, but I dont get any results as well. Just to reiterate, if my array, $data is empty, I want this loop to be terminated, but if it exists, I want it to continue until it's empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `$data->count()` to check if anything were returned in the result set:

```
do {
    $testvar = Str::random(5);
    $data = User::where('password_url', 'LIKE', '%'.$testvar.'%')->get();
}
while ($data->count());
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply. Will try this out and let you know the result. But quick question though, why doesn't empty() work here?

Comment: Not 100% certain, but it could have to do with that even an empty result set isn't really "empty" in your PHP code.

Comment: hmm fair. Would need to look into it to determine the cause. also, $data->count() is perfect! cheers! :D

Comment: User::where('...')->get() returns an empty Laravel Collection if no results are returned, so `empty($data)` returns `false` under those conditions. hence looping infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using below code too:

```
do {
   $testvar = Str::random(5);
   $data = User::where('password_url', 'LIKE', '%'.$testvar.'%')->get();
}while (count($data)!=0);
```

Why i am suggesting this, is because sometimes **$data->count()** return wrong count!!

(It has happened to me so at that time i used **count()** function and it worked!

Comment: ohh i see! thanks for the input mate, I'm trying out different scenarios now :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this,

```
do{
    $testvar = Str::random(5);
     $data = User::where('password_url', 'LIKE', '%'.$testvar.'%')->get();
  }while (!empty($data->count()));
```

Comment: ahhh I think I get it now, by defaulting to !empty($data), it just returns to me a conditional value, not an exact value to refer to.